# Spreadsheet.App.openById stopped working with no change to code or file

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gmail

See my function below.  I have run this code successfully multiple times.  I set up a trigger and it ran a couple of times as well.  I started feeling pretty good about it so I wanted to start using this function on other reports. I set it up on at least 2 other files and they ran successfully manual and with triggers twice before failing.  My original file was running this code for over a month with a trigger and didn't fail once until the other files experience it.  Ironically it was all on 10/29/19 so I don't know if google made some changes.    I don't know if its app script related or I could refine my code to get it to work.

I keep getting this error: *Document 1eQ0uewvBDHVu66fydr76BHqtRJiGUkxtVAVFrkvRQR8 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?).*   Of course for each file and each time that I run the function, the file id changes since I am grabbing a new report from my email each day.  So im assuming that I can use some changes to the bolded section of code below...

```
function getCSV() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"jreport_noreply@datapipe.mediaspectrum.net" subject:"Open SRs"');
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var len = messages.length;
  var message=messages[len-1] //get last message
  var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message

  var xlsxBlob = attachments[0]; // Is supposes that attachments[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18vpXXAuuIfJqww8EoL07dqHSGGHaV3IGRMUCcJz1t40/").getSheetByName("rawdata");
  sheet.clearContents();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

UPDATE 11.4.19 - I have restored my project version prior to 10.29 and I still get the same error.

Update 11.11.19-  I removed *Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file* . This will allow the code to run; however, I cannot do that to each file. So I have identified the issue to be the following.  The converted file is to be deleted.  If we don't delete then I am unable to run the code on multiple files because there is a conflict with the converted id. Which Im sure that is the root issue whether or not we attempt to delete the file. 
 Hopefully someone can help me troubleshoot this. I don't know if it makes sense to rename each file then try to delete it.

Comment: Silly question I guess, but are you using Drive API for this?

Comment: can you tell which version of apps script you are using?

Comment: Hello @DavidColardeau, can you confirm whether the script is actually being completely executed, despite the error you get? (Is your `rawdata` sheet being updated?)

Comment: @kevkeev13 Yes I have Drive Api v2 on for this.  It gives a different error if I don't have that on.

Comment: @J.G. How do I determine that?  Are you referring to a version of app script or a version of my project (for example libraries?)  I am not using libraries.  I have just been copying and reusing the code for different files.

Comment: @carlesgg97  I had one file execute for about 30 days straight.  I set it up on two more projects and I was able to successfully run it approximately 10 times between 2 projects by manually running the function in script editor. I kept running it for testing purposes. The trigger ran twice and has failed each time since.  They all failed on 10/29.  All 3 of my projects code which is identical to the code shown above fail now.

Comment: If you click on the run menu what are the options that you see?

Comment: @J.G.Run >>>  Run Function, Debug Function, Test as add on

Comment: @DavidColardeau What I meant by the last question is, although the trigger execution fails - or it *says* it does - is it actually failing? Could you please check whether the "rawdata" Sheet is being correctly updated? I am asking this because I think this may be bug-related. Thanks!

Comment: @carlesgg97 yes it fails every-time now and provides the same error.  It had run before whether I manually did it within script editor or the trigger. It no longer runs now. The rawdata sheet remains blank. I get no errors when debugging it.  It looks like it runs successfully up until it tries to pull the data from the converted file in drive.

Comment: Update 11.11.19-  I removed *Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file* . This will allow the code to run; however, I cannot do that to each file. So I have identified the issue to be the following.  The converted file is to be deleted.  If we don't delete then I am unable to run the code on multiple files because there is a conflict with the converted id. Which Im sure that is the root issue whether or not we attempt to delete the file. 
 Hopefully someone can help me troubleshoot this. I don't know if it makes sense to rename each file then try to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce your issue. I created a bug issue in the Google Public issue tracker. You can follow the status of the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144330142

Comment: It seems to be writing the sheet now which is great but the deletion of the convertedsheet is not working.  I am receiving the same error.  It would be nice to delete the daily uploads rather than adding a ton of files to the drive to use up space.  Its not terrible to have each days file saved in there but id rather keep my storage down over time.